# Cleaning up Snap Route Handler (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm working through making a site using the snap framework for haskell, and I'm still new to haskell (and snap). I am hoping to find a "better" way to write this route handler.

```
possibleMatches :: Snap ()
possibleMatches = do
  peptideSequence <- getParam "peptide_sequence"
  foundWeight     <- getParam "weight"
  let results = calculationResults (read . C8.unpack $ (fromJust foundWeight)) (fromJust peptideSequence)
  maybe (writeBS "must specify params in URL")
         writeJSON $ Just (results)
```

There are a couple things here:

1. `calculationResults` has signature `:: Float -> ByteString`. I realize i have to do something to get `peptideSequence` from `Maybe ByteString` to `ByteString`, so that seems necessary (and not terribly painful to do), but
2. Converting from `Maybe ByteString` to `Float` seems a bit ridiculous. Is there a better way to handle this? Or is this just something that needs to be pushed down into the `calculationResults` function, and have it handle the conversion?

I suppose I'm trying to expand from my "learning of haskell in a bubble" to include how it's actually done, instead of hammering at the compiler until it finally gives up and says "fine i'll let it through".

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things.

`fromJust` is pretty evil. It's tantamount to `unsafePerformIO` in the world of pure code. You're extracting a value out of a `Maybe` monad w/o pattern matching.

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a

> fromJust Nothing
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

Now, odds are your HTML won't be manipulated maliciously so that those parameters will return `Nothing`. BUT, in case that does happen you should use Snap's built in failure mechanism, it's Snaps implementation of `fail` from the Monad class. It's safer than fromJust and is triggered by a pattern matching failure. You use it by pattern matching on getParam. (`Just peptideSequence <- getParam "peptide_sequence"`)

```
instance Monad Snap where
    (>>=)  = snapBind
    return = snapReturn
    fail   = snapFail
```

snapFail is implemented as

```
snapFail :: String -> Snap a
snapFail !m = Snap $! return $! PassOnProcessing m
```

`PassOnProcessing` will handle pattern match failure gracefully.

More info is in the code:

> http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.8.0.1/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Types.html

Side note:

All monads have a default implementation of fail, but if not overridden the result is often undesired. Any by undesired I mean it will throw an exception that can only be caught inside of the IO monad, but if you're not operating in the IO monad than you're straight out of luck. Snap has overridden the default implementation of fail.

From RWH:

> **Beware of fail.** 
>   Many Monad instances don't override the default
>   implementation of fail that we show here, so in those monads, fail
>   uses error. Calling error is usually highly undesirable, since it
>   throws an exception that callers either cannot catch or will not
>   expect.
>
> Even if you know that right now you're executing in a monad that has
>   fail do something more sensible, we still recommend avoiding it. It's
>   far too easy to cause yourself a problem later when you refactor your
>   code and forget that a previously safe use of fail might be dangerous
>   in its new context.

I still use it though, since it makes sense in this context (Unless a Snap author wants to correct me)

I would have the result of `CalculationResults` return a `JSON` result. I would also handle the `Float` type conversion inside the `CalculationResults` function, might make it cleaner

```
possibleMatches :: Snap ()
possibleMatches = do
  Just peptideSequence <- getParam "peptide_sequence"
  Just foundWeight     <- getParam "weight"
  writeJSON $ calculationResults (read $ C8.unpack foundWeight) peptideSequence
```

or

```
possibleMatches :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
possibleMatches = do
  (peptideSequence, foundWeight) <- (,) <$> getParam "peptide_sequence" <*> getParam "weight"
  writeJSON $ calculationResults (read $ C8.unpack foundWeight) peptideSequence
```

UPDATE:

For more robust error handling in Snap you can use the following code below:

```
catchError :: HasHeist b => ByteString -> Handler b v () -> Handler b v ()
catchError msg action = action `catch` \(e::SomeException) -> go
    where go = do logError msg
                  modifyResponse $ setResponseCode 500
                  render "500"
```

Where "500" is the name of the file `"500.tpl"` located in `snaplets/heist/templates/500.tpl`
To apply it to one of your handlers you would do something like this:

```
handleNewUser :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
handleNewUser = method GET handleGet <|> method POST handlePost
  where
    handleGet = currentUser >>= maybe the404 (\_ -> render "profile")
    handlePost = catchError "Error during login" $ do
          setTimeout 100
          Just login <- getParam "login"
          if | isValid login -> do user <- registerUser "login" "password"
                                   either (\_ -> render "error") (handleUser login) user
             | otherwise -> render "error"
    handleUser = -- etc etc
```

Comment: I would also note that if you want to avoid using `fail`, Snap exports the same function with the name `pass` (and of course the `empty` and `mzero` functions that come with Alternative and MonadPlus).  If you use one of those functions instead of `fail`, you'll guarantee that you won't actually use some other Monad's definition of fail.

Comment: I'll also add that calling `fail` might not be undesirable in a Snap application because that will only result in the current thread being terminated.  If it's a simple AJAX call that doesn't get seen by the user, then that might be acceptable.  Explicit error handling would probably be considered a better practice, but at the cost of introducing more code and some complexity.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, and really highlights how little I know about Haskell. Would you say that RWH and LYAH would give me a solid foundation in monads and presenting data via webapps? So far I've just been using haskell for data processing, but haven't had to interact with the outside world.

Comment: Stuart, glad to help. IME, those books are great. Was looking at the transformers chapter in RWH today, but I think the absolute best resource for learning haskell is the typeclassopedia IMO. I keep going back to it. @mightybyte knows a *lot* about haskell so you should ask him :) http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia

Comment: @StuartNelson see the update I posted for the catchError code above. The exceptions chapter on RWH is real good for understanding that code. If you want to do real world stuff you're going to have to know about transformers, par for the course.

Comment: @StuartNelson: dave's recommendations are excellent.  I can confirm that the Typeclassopedia was a huge boost in my understanding when it came out.  I also might plug my [two](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/2012/04/less-travelled-monad-tutorial-part-1.html) [posts](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/2012/04/ltmt-part-2-monads.html) on monads.  They're not really a tutorial, but they explain things from a different angle that some have found useful.